# Check if certain text was outputted to the screen PHP

Tags: php, javascript, output, noscript

How would I check if certain text was outputted to the screen using PHP?
 For example, I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<noscript>
error: no js
<noscript>
<?php
//detect if the HTML printed out "error: no js"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to detect if HTML printed out the specified `<noscript>` message. Is this possible to do with PHP, or on a PHP page? Is there a better way to stop any scripts if JavaScript is disabled, or if certain output was outputted? 
I would especially like to do this because then I can pass certain output if certain conditions were met, and have the PHP act according to the output.
Thanks!

Comment: PHP has finished running by the time the page is sent to the client, so no, this won't work. You would have to have some client side detection that then requests the appropriate content from your server using an AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is setting a cookie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "jsEnabled=true";
</script>
```

Then, you can do a simple check in PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['jsEnabled'])) {
    // Javascript is enabled!
} else {
    // Javascript is not enabled!
}
```

Comment: is document.cookie set with javascript though? or php?

Comment: then if javascript is disabled, the cookie would not be set? oh wait i see where you go from there lol

Comment: sounds like a good way! but for some reason it is not working!

Comment: I echo the javascript set cookie code (changed all "'s to \") and then added that php right below the js... not working

Comment: @pattyd did you add any output or did you just leave my comments in?

Comment: maybe because that checks for a PHP cookie?

Comment: oh i added `die()` if the else is met, so now i have: `else{die("js not enabled!");}`

Comment: And what do you get? A blank page?

Comment: May sound like a silly question, but did you try disabling JS?

Comment: yes, i successfully disabled it. I even got the <noscript> message, and all my code executed

Comment: Could you paste your entire code into a new question? We're not supposed to carry out extensive discussion in the comments.

Comment: New question available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742622/why-wont-this-code-block-javascript

Comment: just checked my cookies, the jsEnabled cookie is in my browser, no problem there, good idea though!