# Why wont this code detect if javascript is blocked?

Tags: php, javascript, noscript

Okay, I have created a new question to clarify my old one, which is available here: [Check if certain text was outputted to the screen PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742307/check-if-certain-text-was-outputted-to-the-screen-php/16742363?noredirect=1)
Currently I have this code:

```
<?php
echo "

<noscript><h2>! JavaScript is not enabled!!! Features will not work !</h2></noscript>

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    document.cookie= \"jsEnabled=true\";
</script>
";

if (isset($_COOKIE['jsEnabled'])) {
    // Javascript is enabled!
}
 else {
     die("JavaScript is not enabled!");
 }

?>
```

I am not sure why this wont work! It should kill the PHP if JS is disabled! Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this on my system, works fine. The only thing it can be is that your browser is not accepting cookies.

Comment: This should not work the first time a person visits the page, as PHP is executed first, then the HTML is served.

Comment: Make sure you refresh the page - it will only work on the second load, after the javascript has run client side.

Comment: Thanks everybody! That made everyting very clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JavaScript processes **after** PHP has fully given out the page, not before, and not in symbiosis. As such, your PHP call will only work for the second call to the page, not the first.

That is, if you accept cookies in the first place.

If you want to prevent users without JS from using the interface on a page, consider generating the interface in pure JS instead. More reliable.

Comment: @pattyd: No problem, glad it helped! (Grrr, 1 away from that elusive silver badge...)

Comment: 9 more minutes until i can though!

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld, hold :)

Comment: @pattyd: No point apologizing. :-) in the future, remember. The execution stack is usually PHP->JavaScript (after or during DOM load) and not inline.

Comment: @zakhej: you're my hero :-)

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I will remember that, also congrats on silver badge!

Comment: Funny that this gets 10+ upvotes... sometimes SO is unfair :D (of course it's correct)

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: I know. I've provided 10-page-long answers before to have them accepted with +0, and somehow, a (correct) three-line concise answer scores two digits. It may be due to the attention span of third-party voters (i.e. "This answer is too long, I'm out"), which would explain why long, detailed answers really only get upvoted by the OP.